# Hash-optimization and Wilson-maze generation algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, comparative-review, lua

I've finished optimization of Wilson algorithm (maze generation) from "silly and slow" algorithm of choosing unvisited cells:

```
function aux.wilson()
local unvisited_cells = aux.width * aux.height 

local y, x = math.random(aux.sy, aux.height), math.random(aux.sx, aux.width)
aux.grid[y][x].visited = true
unvisited_cells = unvisited_cells - 1

local stx, sty
while true do
  stx, sty = math.random(aux.sx, aux.width), math.random(aux.sy, aux.height) -- Start point
  if aux.grid[sty][stx].visited == false then break end
end

local ix, iy = stx, sty -- sub-vertecies

while unvisited_cells ~= 0 do
  if aux.grid[iy][ix].visited == true then 
    aux.grid[sty][stx].visited = true
    while unvisited_cells ~= 0 do
      if stx == ix and sty == iy then 
        while true do
          stx, sty = math.random(aux.sx, aux.width), math.random(aux.sy, aux.height) 
          if aux.grid[sty][stx].visited == false then break end
        end
        break
        else unvisited_cells = unvisited_cells - 1 end

        local dir = aux.grid[sty][stx].dir
        if dir == "UP" then
          aux.grid[sty-1][stx].visited = true
          aux.grid[sty-1][stx].bottom_wall = false
          sty = sty - 1
        elseif dir == "DOWN" then
          aux.grid[sty+1][stx].visited = true
          aux.grid[sty][stx].bottom_wall = false
          sty = sty + 1
        elseif dir == "LEFT" then
          aux.grid[sty][stx-1].visited = true
          aux.grid[sty][stx-1].right_wall = false
          stx = stx - 1
        elseif dir == "RIGHT" then
          aux.grid[sty][stx+1].visited = true
          aux.grid[sty][stx].right_wall = false
          stx = stx + 1
        end
      end
      ix, iy = stx, sty
    end

    local dir = aux.dirs[math.random(1, 4)]
    if dir == "UP" then -- UP
      if iy-1 >= aux.sy then
        aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "UP"
        iy = iy - 1
      end
    elseif dir == "DOWN" then -- DOWN 
      if iy+1 <= aux.height then 
        aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "DOWN"
        iy = iy + 1
      end
    elseif dir == "RIGHT" then -- RIGHT
      if ix+1 <= aux.width then
        aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "RIGHT"
        ix = ix + 1
      end
    elseif dir == "LEFT" then -- LEFT
      if ix-1 >= aux.sx then
        aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "LEFT"
        ix = ix - 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

to a little bit more clever:

```
function aux.hashKey(x, y)
  return x * aux.height + (y - 1)
end

function aux.deHashKey(value)
  return math.floor(value/aux.height), value%aux.height + 1
end

function aux.hashCells(grid)
local vtable = {}
  for yk, yv in pairs(grid) do
    for xk, xv in pairs(yv) do
      if xv.visited == false then
        vtable[aux.hashKey(xk, yk)] = xv
      end
    end
  end
return vtable
end

function aux.wilson()
local unvisited_cells = aux.width * aux.height
local CellsHash = aux.hashCells(aux.grid)
local key = next(CellsHash, nil)
local vx, vy = aux.deHashKey(key)
CellsHash[key] = nil
aux.grid[vy][vx].visited = true

unvisited_cells = unvisited_cells - 1

key = next(CellsHash, nil)
vx, vy = aux.deHashKey(key)
CellsHash[key] = nil

local stx, sty = vx, vy

local ix, iy = stx, sty -- sub-vertecies

while unvisited_cells ~= 0 do
  if aux.grid[iy][ix].visited == true then 
    aux.grid[sty][stx].visited = true
    CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx, sty)] = nil
    while unvisited_cells ~= 0 do
      if stx == ix and sty == iy then 
        key = next(CellsHash, nil)
        vx, vy = aux.deHashKey(key)
        CellsHash[key] = nil

        stx, sty = vx, vy
        break
        else unvisited_cells = unvisited_cells - 1 end

        local dir = aux.grid[sty][stx].dir
        if dir == "UP" then
          aux.grid[sty-1][stx].visited = true
          CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx, sty-1)] = nil
          aux.grid[sty-1][stx].bottom_wall = false
          sty = sty - 1
        elseif dir == "DOWN" then
          aux.grid[sty+1][stx].visited = true
          CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx, sty+1)] = nil
          aux.grid[sty][stx].bottom_wall = false
          sty = sty + 1
        elseif dir == "LEFT" then
          aux.grid[sty][stx-1].visited = true
          CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx-1, sty)] = nil
          aux.grid[sty][stx-1].right_wall = false
          stx = stx - 1
        elseif dir == "RIGHT" then
          aux.grid[sty][stx+1].visited = true
          CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx+1, sty)] = nil
          aux.grid[sty][stx].right_wall = false
          stx = stx + 1
        end
      end
      ix, iy = stx, sty
    end

    local dir = aux.dirs[math.random(1, 4)]
    if dir == "UP" then -- UP
      if iy-1 >= aux.sy then
        aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "UP"
        iy = iy - 1
      end
    elseif dir == "DOWN" then -- DOWN 
      if iy+1 <= aux.height then 
        aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "DOWN"
        iy = iy + 1
      end
    elseif dir == "RIGHT" then -- RIGHT
      if ix+1 <= aux.width then
        aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "RIGHT"
        ix = ix + 1
      end
    elseif dir == "LEFT" then -- LEFT
      if ix-1 >= aux.sx then
        aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "LEFT"
        ix = ix - 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I noticed, that on the small grid (100x100), it works almost the same, but on the bigger grid (like 1000x1000), first version works in about 3-4 seconds, but the second version just freezes. And I really can' understand why. I don't see any operations, that can cause big-time issues.

I will really appreciate any advice or comments about optimization and speed of the both algorithm.

UPD1: I forgot to say, that there is no problem in creating hash-table or grid itself, it is done in 2-3 seconds always. So, I suspect problem either in "next" function, or, maybe, in hash-function, that creates conflicts and make endless-loop.

UPD2: Ok, after some research and profiling I've found, that the problem was in a next function. Hash-table and collision solving-mechanism that are hidden behind Lua next-function are really slow for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, your first post looks good except perhaps the indentation suffered a bit while pasting here? Otherwise hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Thank you! About indentation, I think, the problem is in the Lua itself. It has many "do"/"end" blocks, that makes code slightly unreadable. And something went wrong with pasting from Sublime Text 3 too, as I can see. But, anyway, next time I will try to reindent it better.

Comment: I think you can still edit it, that'd prevent people from commenting on it unnecessarily :)

Comment: I don't really know how to fix it, because it is original Lua intimidation, and any attempt to change it will probably make code fully unreadable.

Comment: I think you mean *indentation*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, indentation of course.

Comment: @greybeard I fixed indentation (yup, not intimidation), I hope it is better now.

Comment: @greybeard I don't really think that it is a good idea to refactor whole code right now. Sadly, the speed-problem still is the main problem.

Comment: (Don't write, _never_ present uncommented code!) I can see "the if-statements" following `dir = aux.dirs[math.random(1, 4)]` - does it hurt if neither `ix` nor `iy` change?

Comment: @greybeard If I understood you right, no, it doesn't. https://i.imgur.com/gbyZBbu.png
Dirs are stored in grid-cells, so, it changes only direction for one of the cell.
// Yes, probably, my another mistake – I've not written comments, but, I can justify myself, that this is my first post here :D

Comment: Wait - `stx, sty` get chosen such that `aux.grid[sty][stx].visited == false`, `ix, iy` get initialised to `stx, sty`, and Wilson continues to loop doing anything `if aux.grid[iy][ix].visited == true`, if at all?

Comment: @greybeard Where do you see it? 'Walking' doesn't care about visited/unvisited cells, it cares only about removing loops. After assigning stx, sty to ix, iy, both loops break and continue randomly walking.

Comment: I see that in the `"silly and slow"` code - selection _before_ `both loops`, check in the outer.

Comment: @greybeard anyway, the problem has been found. C-implementation of hash-table mechanism of next() function is slow in some cases like next(table, nil). Profiler shows 93% of time spent on this function. next(CellsHash, key) solved that problem and now maze generates in 2 seconds. Thank all of you for trying to help and refactor some of this code =)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Lua, but one thing that stands out is your use of `== true`/`== false` in `if` statements.

Code in any language gets more readable by omitting `== true` and substituting `not x` for `x == false`. The expressions are already usable as booleans, you don't have to explicitly compare them to a constant.

Comment: Yes, you are right about it. But the problem is, that Lua has 2 different values for «false». (false itself and nil, which means variable hadn't been declared/defined). The same for true – true is everything, that is not false or nil, so == true / == false are just for clarifying which values program should waiting for.

Comment: `so == true / == false are just for clarifying which values program should waiting for` my opinion: _Don't._ - it is bound to irritate readers (_Just_ why _do other values need to be excluded here?_) and _may_ introduce errors if other values interpreted the same _do_ occur and shouldn't be handled differently after all. (_If and when_ you are convinced standard evaluation to be inappropriate, leave a (code-) comment. (Formulating that may even lead to an insight/cleaner code…))

Comment: @greybeard Thank you for your advices. I will edit code when I arrive at home. Intimidation and conditions are important, of course, but the main problem is speed of that code, and it won't help a lot.